# How to list the db contexts registered in a project with console?

Tags: entity-framework-core

The console states that "More than one DbContext was found".

I actually only have one context in the project.

How can I list the contexts in the project to locate the other context and remove the reference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the EF Core tools to list the available `DbContext` in your project:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext list
```

> **dotnet ef dbcontext list**
>
> Lists available DbContext types

[Entity Framework Core tools reference - .NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-list)

Note: To use the CLI, you need to install the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design/2.2.6) NuGet package, since it's not available in Console apps by default.

As per why this is happening, maybe you are using a package which itself has a DbContext. One example is using `IdentityServer` with EFCore.

Comment: dotnet ef dbcontext list  did the trick. There was a boiler plate db context hanging around from when the project was first initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Run This code below in package manager console, it will list the DbContext. In my case it was being used in one Nuget Pakage ..HealthChecksDb

-> DbContext